# Print perfect web word processor?

Tags: html, printing, ms-word

I'm looking for a web based word processor. I'd like something that prints exactly what the user sees on the screen.

It's for an internal app so I don't need something available only through the Internet.

Comment: Do you need code or just the web word processor? If the latter, you might be interested in using Google Docs: http://docs.google.com/

Comment: Google docs is good but it's online (Internet access needed) and the layout is not exactly the same between what you see on the screen and the printed version.

Comment: You're better off getting WYSIWYM working rather than WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 1):

You will find it **very very hard** to have a consistent experience on screen and on users's computers. If you can control the environment to a point where you can force all users to use the same browser on the same OS you'll be fine, otherwise you should try a more hybrid approach. Something that can have slight print variations but also works fine.

Google Docs uses a verry interesting method for presenting the info to the user *before* printing. **They convert your page to a PDF, prior to printing** and there you can see exactly what will be printed or not. If you're good to go, shot. If not you can come back to the textarea and keep iterating.